# How to check the blockchain height in hyperledger-fabric

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am playing with hyperledger-fabric v.1.0 - actually a newbie. How can I check the chain height ? Is there a command or something that I can use to "ask" about the blockchain height? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

Well, you have a few options of how you can do it:

1. You can leverage `peer cli` command line tool to obtain latest available block by running

   ```
   peer channel fetch newest -o ordererIP:7050 -c mychannel  last.block
   ```

Next you can leverage `configtxlator` to decode content of the block as following:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @last.block http://localhost:7059/protolator/decode/common.Block
```

(note you need to start `configtxlator` first)

2. Alternative path assumes you are going to use one of available SDK's to invoke QSCC (Query System ChainCode) with `GetChainInfo` command. This will return you back following structure:

   ```
   type BlockchainInfo struct {
        Height            uint64 `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=height" json:"height,omitempty"`
        CurrentBlockHash  []byte `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=currentBlockHash,proto3" json:"currentBlockHash,omitempty"`
        PreviousBlockHash []byte `protobuf:"bytes,3,opt,name=previousBlockHash,proto3" json:"previousBlockHash,omitempty"`
   }
   ```

Which has information about current ledger height.

Comment: Thanks Artem. your answer is way more elegant and flexible.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative.
Using the `cli peer` command line (for example `docker exec -it cli bash`)  you can do:

`peer channel getinfo -c mychannel`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found something - maybe cumbersome, but better than nothing:

Command:

```
docker logs -f peer0.org1.example.com 2>&1 | grep blockNo
```

Check for the "latest" line in the output, something like:

> 2017-07-18 19:40:39.586 UTC [historyleveldb] Commit -> DEBU b75b Channel [mychannel]: Updates committed to history database for blockNo [34]

So, if I am not wrong, in this case the block height is: 34

Thanks

Comment: It start from `0`, so it should plus 1 than you got.

Answer (score 0):

you can use blockchain-explorer (UI tool)
https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer

Answer (score -1):

You should also be able to use the fabric CORE API (JSON/REST).

See the docs for the Blockchain GET/chain operation at;

https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/blob/master/docs/API/CoreAPI.md#rest-api

Comment: This answer references the archived, and defunct original code base of Hyperledger Fabric v0.5. The REST API has been deprecated and removed in v1.0.x and a new REST SDK is being developed in its place.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So is this the correct link ? - http://fabricrepo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/API/CoreAPI/#rest-api

Comment: no, the new REST SDK is rather nascent. The repo is here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-rest but is still a work in progress.